# Axios response.data object returns garbage on simple API GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I wrote a quick test function to try out Axios, and the response.data object that gets returns is garbled. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong— I've tried Googling around for this to no avail, and all of the Axios tutorials I've found seem to be doing exactly what I'm doing.

Here's the GET request I make:

```
var axios = require('axios');
const getCatFact = async () => {
  const url = "https://catfact.ninja/fact";

  const response = await axios.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
  });
  console.log(response.data);
};

getCatFact();
```

And here's what the responses look like:

```
%O�j�@
      ��aO-����������{�nٕ������a4��0J��>���+�,D�ˢ
                                                �bV�G��/I�Cw�Rf¤L���Z�5w����]ӄ���s������
I.b�z"�IR��M����(N3��Y���귴���m�ۤ�   ��Xuz���t�uS�y\��5=61������4y
                                                                 �����!{��
```

I've tried:

- Loading the URL in Chrome and making the GET request via Postman to validate that the API itself is not the problem.
- Testing with a different API (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1), which has the same issue.

I'm expecting the snippet above to return a response that looks something like this:

```
{"fact":"Julius Ceasar, Henri II, Charles XI, and Napoleon were all afraid of cats.","length":74}
```

Comment: This is a known [Axios bug](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298). Next time check the issues list first

Answer (score 2):

### In v1.2.1, it is fixed this error.

You need to add `Accept-Encoding` with 'application/json' in axios get header.

```
var axios = require('axios');
const getCatFact = async () => {
  const url = "https://catfact.ninja/fact";

  const response = await axios.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json'
    }
  });
  console.log(response.data);
};

getCatFact();
```

Will be get this result

```
$ node get-cat.js
{
  fact: 'Cats have about 130,000 hairs per square inch (20,155 hairs per square
centimeter).',
  length: 83
}
```

Comment: _"You need to add Accept-Encoding"_... this won't be a requirement once Axios fixes their bug so this answer will age poorly

Comment: It only solution at this time and do not hurt this adding code even after fix defect.

Comment: This answer saved me